# How to call twice a subscribed HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on app that's using SSR.
While entering the app I'm sending a request to get some products.
Everything works fine, because I don't see the request in browser.
If user was logged in the app API should return different values.
The information if user is logged is held in `localStorage` as an `idToken`.
If a request is sent in a browser the `idToken` is added to the header.
API checks if the `idToken` is logged or not.

Now if I send the request in prerender i get values for an unlogged user, then in browser I check if I have the `idToken` and if so I want to execute the HTTP request once again to get the right values.
But since the HTTP request is already subscribed the request isn't executed again in browser.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Should I unsubscribe first?

#### collection.service.ts:

```
getProductHome() {
  return this.apiservice.get(this.COLLECTION_CONF_TOKEN.urlHomeProducts, {});
}
```

#### main.ts:

```
if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
  this.collectionservice.getProductHome().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.newProducts = res;
    }
  );
} else if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) && isLogged) {
  this.collectionservice.getProductHome().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.newProducts = res;
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `getProductHome()` after you log in and get the token? I can't say that you are doing by this code alone, because the main.ts should be called once.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two things to consider:

1. Are you calling the `getProductHome()` after Authenticated? If you are not, you should. The main.ts should be called once only so I guess it's not passing through that code again.
2. If you have two calls, maybe your problems comes from the http calls **cache** and not the `Subscription`.

You can add Headers to disable the cache like this in the **http request headers**:

```
headers = new Headers({
        'Cache-Control':  'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post- 
                            check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'
    });
```

Or you can add html tags like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```